# Android ListView setEmptyView

Tags: android

I am populating listView using webservice; I want to display a message when there is no result. I used following code on activity but it is working fine; But when data is being loaded it still shows empty message in listview.

```
@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();

    View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
    TextView empty1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
    empty1.setText("No Channels Found!");
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setEmptyView(empty);
}
```

Comment: does the solution work if you comment out all the above code?

Comment: Try to set the visibility of the empty view to Invisible after list is loaded. empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: @Pork it works; but it shows empty message when data is being loaded;

Comment: @Juangcg it worked :) thanks; I did this in oncreate ; 
View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: @ManoBili I copy the comment as an answer so you can mark this as resolved.

Comment: Setting the visibility on the on the emptyview depends on undefined behavior of the ListView; namely that it will actually be shown if the data comes back with 0 results. It happens to work, now, on the version being tested, but it's less safe than just not setting an emptyview during a time when the ListView will be empty and you do not want to see the emptyview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the visibility of the empty view to Invisible after list is loaded. empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

The empty view will be shown whenever your adapter returns a count of 0. That will include the time when your data is loading. If you don't want that behavior then don't set an empty view until after your data has loaded.